# Synchronized access to file

Tags: java, android

I want to implement my own logger that write logs in file. It could be run from many threads and an issue is how to synchronized access to log file.

```
   private synchronized static void writeToFile(String tag, String msg, 
        Throwable tr, Context ctx) {
    try {
        String s = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        File f = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        Log.i(TAG, "Path to app " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        File l = new File(f, "log.txt");
        if (!l.exists()) {
            l.createNewFile();
        }

        String e = Log.getStackTraceString(tr);
        StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();
        b.append(HttpCommand.getDateForUrl(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        b.append(tag);
        b.append(msg);
        b.append(e);
        b.append(s);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(l);
        out.write(b.toString().getBytes());
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Failed to create backup");
    }
}
```

Is it enough to sync access to database with sync by class if I pass it in different threads?

```
synchronized(X.class) {
    writeTiFile()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your writeToFile() function is synchronized, you don't have to wrap any calls to it with the synchronized {} block.

See here for more info:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: Yes, but what if I remove static modifier and pass a many instance in threads?

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConcurrentLinkedQueue, put all messages to Queue and create thread that take from queue and write it to file.